# Add elements with arguments in an array with java

Tags: java

I want to add a new element that has several arguments in an array. I know how to add with just one argument, but with more i don't know.

My code is:

```
private Calculate[] calculation;

public Element(int numElements) {
    calculation = new Calculate[numElements];
}    
public void addElement(Date elementDate, double price, ElementType type) {
    int numElements = elements.length;
    int i = 0;

    if (i < numElements) {
        Calculate[i] = calculation.elementDate;
        Calculate[i] = calculation.price;
        Calculate[i] = calculation.type;
        i++;    
    }
}
```

Comment: just use for loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume Calculate is a class defined else where with a constructor

There is a couple of issues in this piece of code:
You want to update the array, but specify array. `Calculate[]` is the array type. The name if the array is `calculation`. The other thing is that you are trying to access `calculation.elementDate` etc. but since that is an array, it does not have the field elementDate. I assume your Calculate class has that field. Also, you are not applying a loop. So currently your code will only update the array on index 0.

My code:

```
public void addElement(Date elementDate, double price, ElementType type) {
    for(int i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) { // for loop over all elements in your array
        Calculate calculate = new Calculate(elementDate, price, type) // I assume this constructor is available to initialize the Calculate object
        calculation[i] = calculate;
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

```
Calculate[i] = calculation.elementDate;
Calculate[i] = calculation.price;
Calculate[i] = calculation.type;
```

You shouldn't assign to the same array index 3 times. You're overriding what you've just set.

Try this (`Calculate` should have a constructor):

```
Calculate[i] = new Calculate(elementDate, price, type);
```

You're also maintaining an index `i`, but you're not looping over anything. `i` is just incremented from from zero to one and is not really used (apart from an almost useless conditional check).

I suggest you read over [a beginners Java tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/). You seem to be missing a lot of the fundamentals, and Stack Overflow is not a place where we should have to show you how to write a for-loop. It's well-documented and demonstrated in a tonne of tutorials already.